# Livewire 3 how to automatically assign data to public property?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I wanted to ask if there is a better way to create an update form using livewire 3? My current code doesn't seem effective if it has lots of properties in one form

```
public function openModalAkuisisi($uuid)
{
    $this->reloadData();

    $this->outlet = Outlet::akuisisi()->with(['regional', 'area', 'horecaGroup', 'horecaOutlet', 'statusTracking'])->whereUuid($uuid)->firstOrFail();

    $this->tp_code = $this->outlet->tp_code;
    $this->outlet_code = $this->outlet->outlet_code;
    $this->outlet_name = $this->outlet->outlet_name;
    $this->alamat = $this->outlet->alamat;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....

    $this->dispatch('open_modal');
}
```

Is there a better way to assign values to public properties with query results from Eloquent directly without writing them one by one? Maybe extract this validation rules data using `https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/forms` ?

```
$this->outlet = Outlet::akuisisi()->with(['regional', 'area', 'horecaGroup', 'horecaOutlet', 'statusTracking'])->whereUuid($uuid)->firstOrFail();
$this->form = $this->outlet;
```

So...my model inside form can bind with this data. Is that possible todo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Bulk Assignment](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/properties#bulk-assignment) provided by Livewire.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```php
public function openModalAkuisisi(string $uuid): void
{
    $this->reloadData();

    $this->outlet = Outlet::akuisisi()
        ->with(['regional', 'area', 'horecaGroup', 'horecaOutlet', 'statusTracking'])
        ->whereUuid($uuid)
        ->firstOrFail();

    $this->fill($this->outlet->only([
        'tp_code',
        'outlet_code',
        'outlet_name',
        'alamat',
        // ... Add other properties
    ]));

    $this->dispatch('open_modal');
}
```

If you want to put it into a Livewire Form, you could do the same:

```php
namespace App\Livewire\Forms;

use App\Models\Outlet;
use Livewire\Form;

final class OutletForm extends Form
{
    public Outlet $outlet;

    public string $tp_code;
    public string $outlet_code;
    public string $outlet_name;
    public string $alamat;
    // ... Define all the properties.

    public function set(Outlet $outlet): void
    {
        $this->outlet = $outlet;

        $this->fill($outlet->only([
            'tp_code',
            'outlet_code',
            'outlet_name',
            'alamat',
            // ... Add other properties
        ]));
    }
}
```

And your Livewire component would look something like this:

```php
namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Livewire\Forms\OutletForm;
use App\Models\Outlet;
use Livewire\Component;

final class EditarOutlet extends Component
{
    public OutletForm $form;

    public function openModalAkuisisi(string $uuid): void
    {
        $this->reloadData();

        $this->outlet = Outlet::akuisisi()
            ->with(['regional', 'area', 'horecaGroup', 'horecaOutlet', 'statusTracking'])
            ->whereUuid($uuid)
            ->firstOrFail();

        $this->form->set($outlet);

        $this->dispatch('open_modal');
    }

    // Other methods of your component
}
```